# Displaying only the main category node in the Single Product Page.instead of subcategories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am a newbie to nopcommerce mvc framework.I have a side category navigation which shows all the categories and subcategories in almost all pages where i need, except in single product page.In the single product page,Side menu displays only the main categories whereas i wanted to display main category and the subcategory.Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your product details view inherit from the _ColumnsTwo.cshtml